# Как данные из цикла вывести в 2 строки?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, slider, циклы

Есть у меня *карусель*, в которую данные с помощью цикла:

```
<?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>
<?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

выводятся в одну строку - вот так:

```html
<ul>
  <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
    <div>
      <li>product 1</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>product 2</li>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</ul>
```

[ссылка на фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/TWtwt/360/)

Как сделать вывод этих же данных с помощью этого же цикла, но уже в 2 строки?

Чтобы на выходе уже получилось вот так - [ссылка на фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/TWtwt/359/)

Comment: Что вы в своем вопросе подразумеваете под "одной строкой"? Хоть убейте что тут, что в примере на jsfiddle.net одной строки не вижу.

Comment: @Visman я же в примере показал 2 строки, которые мне и нужно получить из цикла, а не одну - что и написал..

Comment: У вас нет тут одной строки. Кнопку "Выполнить код" нажмите и убедитесь.

Comment: @Visman исправил описание

Comment: Вы наверное хотели сказать два столбца? В "выполнить код" все так как надо, а в jsfiddle не так :)

Comment: @androschuk нет, я все правильно сказал - в 2 строки и фидлах все так - что вам не ясно-то?

Answer (score 1):

В css добавьте правило

```
#owl-demo > div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Пример тут http://jsfiddle.net/o0qfha65/

**UPD по измененному вопросу**
Вот так сделал на чистом css

```
#owl-demo > div {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 100px;
}
#owl-demo > div:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: -120px;
}
```

для кода такого вида

```
<ul>
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
    <div>
        <li>product 1</li>
    </div>
    <div>
        <li>product 2</li>
    </div>
    <div>
        <li>product 3</li>
    </div>
    <div>
        <li>product 4</li>
    </div>
    <div>
        <li>product 5</li>
    </div>
    <div>
        <li>product 6</li>
    </div>
</div>
</ul>
```

Пример тут http://jsfiddle.net/oxfb3Laq/